# dmesg filling up with error message that are just a hex number

Tags: debian, arm, dmesg, cubieboard

I've got a Cubietruck running debian 8.4, and it seems to be running OK, but just happened to do a dmesg, and found that I was getting a lot of message consisting of just a hex number...

```
[ 3353.382330] 0x768
[ 3358.591375] 0x76b
[ 3363.803134] 0x76b
[ 3369.023739] 0x766
[ 3374.234059] 0x767
[ 3379.442238] 0x76d
```

Other than the messages, the system seems to be running fine, but I suspect this means I have a hardware failure coming, or alternatively, when I upgraded from debian 7.x with apt-get, something didn't go exactly right.

Any suggestions as to how I determine what this is about?

I don't even have a keyword to google!

Comment: Did you check what was shown just before that?  You can simply output it to a file to find it.

Comment: IIUC these are memory locations..

Comment: The computer seems to be running OK, but this problem is still a problem.  If these are memory locations... how do I identify what it means?   Does it mean bad ram or what?